# Sendgrid CSS button isn't showing correctly

Tags: html, css, sendgrid

I've got the following code - it's a CSS button with "snow" on top. It's showing correctly in Sendgrid's "preview" and on other rendering platforms, but when I send it, the "snow" does not appear.

```
<head>

</head>

<body>
<div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-text-center" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
<button class="uk-button uk-button-large" style="min-width: 200px; display: inline-block; overflow: visible; position: relative; padding: 0px 0px; margin: 0; font: inherit; color: #fff; box-sizing: border-box; background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 0 -50%,

    url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 50% -50%,
    url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 100% -50%, red; line-height: 34px; min-height: 34px; font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 500px; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: Lato,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight: 300; letter-spacing: 1.5px; -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-out,background .3s ease-out,opacity .3s ease-out,border-color .3s ease-out; transition: background-color .3s ease-out,background .3s ease-out,opacity .3s ease-out,border-color .3s ease-out;">
  I'm IN!
</button></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you could give us an image of how the button is supposed to look?

Comment: Yes - the original code is here (with an image) https://codepen.io/rampen/pen/NbEeyG @OfficerErikK

Comment: When you say send it, what do you mean? Are you referencing to when you click on the button?

Comment: @OfficerErikK If I use the preview feature, the button looks as it should (eg with the "snow" on top. When I send a test email - the snow won't show in my email. I'm not blocking images or anything as far as I'm aware.

Comment: What email service do you use?

Comment: @OfficerErikK Gmail

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error due to some reason..But you can resolve it  by applying inline styling. Because we are just creating a one-off email, inline styles aren't quite as bad as they are on a website

Comment: Thanks. The code (see the example) is already inline...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).